Third-party identity provider (AWS) sync with own database
My team and I are developing an app based on microservices. We are starting to use AWS Cognito for authentication, but we want to store every user in our own database as well, so that we can populate that table with extra information. I know Cognito has custom attributes but we prefer not to go that route.
Furthermore, we are creating a microservice that will manage that user extra information and their relationships with other entities.
I've learned that Cognito has lambda triggers like post-confirmation which would be great to achieve want we want (plus add an SQS to handle this async).
My question is the following, what is that lambda suppose to do ideally ? If you've been in similar situations, what has been your experience ?

We could write all the code for connecting to our database, and storing the user right in that Lambda, but I feel like we are duplicating the code/responsabilities of our users microservice

We could create an endpoint in our microservice to register users, and call it from our lambda, but then what should we do to make sure we are only accepting calls from our lambda and not other unwanted client ?

We have our microservice split in such a way we could easily consider the usecase logic a library, so it is technically possible to import it in our lambda, but it doesn't feel appropiate.


